# BlockingCollection and CancellationToken passing

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Why is the `CancellationToken` for a `BlockingCollection` not passed in the constructor of`BlockingCollection`?

The token has to be passed into the `Take` and `Add` methods, what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would using the ctor be better?

I can imagine using a CancellationToken for Take() but not for Add().
Or using different tokens.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! There is a token for add, since you can specify a capacity for the collection. Adding to a full collection will block (this is cancelable with the token). I assumed that there is a BlockingCollection constructor taking a token that is used for all Add and Take operations. I am asking that question because I fear that I might misunderstand something in the cancellation token handling.

Comment: It is driven by the usage pattern. Using 1 token for Add and Take would only be useful in a few situations.

Answer (score 2):

CancellationToken is used to support "operation cancellation".  this is more general concept than a object instance with a boolean field meaning "active/disabled".  It supports concurrency, object reuse and other interesting scenarios.

So the operations are Add() and Take() and each of them can be long-running due to the collection being empty or full.  If the caller wants the option to cancel a long-running method call, then they pass in a token and signal it if needed.